# MVC pattern + ( REST) View Confusion

Tags: rest, mvc

I have been trying to build an **MVC** structured RESTapi.Since it's going to return JSON only,is it right that my View will just have a **header**  and that the view will output the JSON also?

I planed to implement *JsonSerializable* than to do some magic with it in the controller/model part, than to output it in the view.

Is it the right way?

I feel that my view is small if i would do it this way,but i red lots of articles about it and i think that it's right.Since it't returning only JSON and there is no html/css/js.

Since i planed to move this part to another domain for example:**api.domain.com**

Than i would make the visual part in Angular probably and it would use the **api.domain.com**

Comment: Could you share any of the links (articles) where supposedly they  implement this approach?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164468/php-mvc-restful-api

Comment: Looking at other MVCs (http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-4-mvc-rest-example-json/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275613/is-mvc-restful-by-design

Comment: I could go like this till tomorrow @Laiv the point is that i wanted someone to explain me in detail with references to tell me it's the right way.Tho i could't think of another when reading all this stuff

Comment: Thx. I just want to see exactly what's your point of view through these post.

Comment: Just a little hint. The example with Spring is just a fairly common example of Spring' REST API implentation that has nothing to do with MVC. MVC is the Spring project where these features comes from. When implementing REST API  the V of the MVC falls apart from the MC.

Comment: What I don't understand is this sentence `my View will just have a header and that the view will output the JSON also?` what do you mean by *have a header*?

Comment: I don't agree with you about the 'REST API the V of the MVC falls apart from the MC'.MVC (Model View Controller).The model talks to the database(ORM or anything else)...The model is responsible for holding the functions and variables that are involved with whatever it’s representing.The controllers job is to know which model should be used and thats it.When the process has been done ,the data from the model goes back to the controller and the controller calls the view.The view is what the controller returns to the user.It helps display the retireved data.I don't know how can you say that the

Comment: V can fall of?Makes no sense.And yes the header will just put content-type.....Don't know whats confusing about that.

Comment: And to be more detailed the controller will be managed by the router....

Comment: RESTful APIs have nothing to do with MVC. That's it. The MVC is a frontend design pattern that could cohexist with the API in the Server side but not necessarily. In your case there's not even MVC. Just API (MC) and MVVM (angular app). That's why I say in your approach, there's no MVC in the API rest. Just MC.

Comment: And about the Spring MVC :D Again i have to explain in detail.......'Looking at other MVCs' means exploring the structure of it.....

Comment: @tereško please explain him :D

Comment: I don't have nerves to explain you more....Hope tereško answers you and explains you the thing better :D

Comment: PHP -> MVC pattern <- + REST i can't be more clear i think?

Comment: Well It's not me who needs helps to understand how RESTful API works and how are they implemented. @Teresko explain him that. Good luck :-D

Comment: Can you please send me the reference to the MC pattern?@Laiv

Comment: @Laiv 'Views are the data (HTML, XML, JSON, or otherwise) returned by the controller in response to an HTTP GET request.' Send me references for everything you say since i think that you are writing non sense here

Comment: What are you talking about MC(model view)?How will you represent the data?The Angular part here was just to show that i will use that API in it.'Since i planed to move this part to another domain for example:api.domain.com

Than i would make the visual part in Angular probably and it would use the api.domain.com'->my post

Comment: How will the data be represented than?My goal is to hold to one pattern ,and to build it upon it not to make some mixed code that will not make sense latter.

Answer (score 1):

A View is something you look at.  Unless there is something very unusual about your user base, most of them aren't going to want to look at JSON.

If you need to return JSON from an MVC controller action, the traditional way to spit that data out is to use a [JSONresult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json(System.Object)) and not a [ViewResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View). The JSON data would typically be output in the body, not in the headers, using a content-type of [application/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type).  If you are using .NET, code might look like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod()
{
    return Json(new {foo="fooValue", bar="barValue"});
}
```

Comment: I wrote 'View will just have a header and that it will output the JSON' you might be miss undarstood this part.No I built it in PHP.Here is the project https://github.com/rarslan/PHP-MVC-RESTful-API

Comment: My question was if it is okay.Since the controller/model will send the serialized Json to the view and it will have just a header and encode it.